# jQuery $.get and Rails

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a script that makes an Ajax call to one of my rails resources to grab all the notes for a particular page.

Rails Controller:

```
def show
    if request.xhr?
      @page = Page.find(params[:page_id])
      @note = Note.find_by_page_id(params[:page_id])
      @user = User.where("user_id = ?", @note.user_id)
    end
  end
```

jQuery $.get ajax:

```
function viewNotes(page_id){
            $.get('/pages/' + page_id + '/notes', function(data){
                $("#note_content").html(data);
            });
        }
```

I am getting this error Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 (I am using Google Chrome for testing)

Any ideas on why this error would occur?

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the "data" variable to the console to make sure that it has the proper contents.  The jQuery looks valid to me.

Comment: thanks for the help! It ended up being that first I was modifying the wrong controller and two I was not using the render functionality properly. But whats odd is that Chrome was throwing up while Firefox was working just fine. Regardless, I just need to sleep more before coding lol